# iOS - memory efficiency on loading image via code OR utility panel

Tags: memory-management, uiimageview

for loading only one image, 1st step is to drag a `UIImageView` to the screen.
Now I can assign an `IBOutlet` to it and load the image in code. And it adds the `setImage=nil` in `viewDidUnload` for me.
Or I can just use the utility panel to assign that image to the `UIImage` and write no code. But is this as efficient as that? Better? Worse?
How about assigning images to buttons? Is it better to assign them in code or just selecting the button's image from the utility panel?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are comparing doing something in interface builder to programatically, correct? They are both equally the same considering you use the same sort of memory management (nil out the ivar, etc.). Basically the xib does the exact same thing as coding it out when it comes down to it, it is just a matter of preference.

Comment: when assigning the image to a UIImageView or a button in interface builder, no writing code is needed. I was just wondering if the code will be generated in the compile time or not? If I assign an image in the interface builder, I don't need to write 1 line of code. No IBOutlets or setImage = nil.
I'm using ARC either.
any suggestions?

Comment: Yes the code will be compiled at compile time from interface builder. ARC will come into play and reduce your app's memory footprint if you set the image of your ivar to nil. You would still need to do that sort of thing of course. You should think of IB as something that helps you design/initialize the GUI, not maintain it. For instance even animations for your GUI would need to be done programmatically. I would personally recommend you go with IB for designing your GUI as it really reduces the amount of code required and makes it trivial to make changes to your interface in the future.